# What is MongoDB's Role-Based Access Control?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, roles, role-based-access-control

What is MongoDB's Role-Based Access Control?

I am fairly new to MongoDB. I was going through the [mongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/#roles) of its Role-Based Access Control feature.

I am a bit confused.

Is this the same as adding a roles array in a user schema(as in the example below)?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: type: String,
  email: type: String,
  roles: ['admin'],
})
```

Or is it adding permissions to users who can access and manipulate the DB directly without the use of apis?

Comment: When you connect your Mongoose code to MongoDB, you will have given it a username and password (in addition to the server URL). What that user can do (which databases can be accessed for example) can be configured using roles.

Answer (score 1):

Well your question is not straight forward.... The essence of the role is to allow users perform some certain operations on the database
For example
Given the example above an a user registered with an admin may be granted permission to delete other users,  add,  edit and so on.